# 'id' that points to some class or any subclass

Tags: objective-c

so in Objective-C I can have a reference to object that implements certain protocol like this:

```
id<MyAwesomeProtocol> object;
```

I could have a reference to some class, like this:

```
MyAwesomeClass *object;
```

I was wondering, what should I do to have reference to MyAwesomeClass, or any sub-class.

I could of course just use `id` but I'd like to know if there is any better way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To have reference to an object of your class or its subclasses you still can write

```
MyAwesomeClass *object;
```

Comment: Oh nice, I thought it would throw errors - because subclass is actually a different class. This is great, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In general it is better to use `NSObject*` instead of `id`. All objective-C objects are decendants for `NSObject` so why ignore all the `NSObject` goodies?

If you are dealing with `MyAwesomeClass` or subclasses I would use `MyAwesomeClass` *object. If you are just using the protocol methods (in the context of the protocol) then I would use `NSObject <MyAwesomeProtocol> *object`.

Comment: The convention is to use id rather than NSObject* when you don't know or care about the class of the object.  If you were to use NSObject* you'd get compiler warnings when sending messages that NSObject does not respond to.

Comment: Note that not every Objective-C objects are descendants of NSObject. There are currently two root classes in the Foundation framework: NSObject and NSProxy.